# Loop through each cell

Tags: excel, loops

So, basically what am I doing is working at making a game called Minesweeper with MS Excel. And now I have an error coming out after I try to run my ''new game'' and it say theres something wrong with

> For Each myCell In Range(strBoardSize)

My full code is made to look at all cells in the range and if a cell is next to any number of items it will show the number of items in its periphery. I understand there may be easier ways to code it, but please don't judge me cause I'm a beginner.

```
Sub WorkOutMines()

Dim myCell As Range
Dim intCountSurroundingCells

For Each myCell In Range(strBoardSize)

intCountSurroundingCells = 0

If myCell.Value = "x" Then
Else
    If myCell.Offset(-1, -1).Value = "x" Then
        intCountSurroundingCells = intCountSurroundingCells + 1
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "x" Then
        intCountSurroundingCells = intCountSurroundingCells + 1
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = "x" Then
        intCountSurroundingCells = intCountSurroundingCells + 1
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "x" Then
        intCountSurroundingCells = intCountSurroundingCells + 1
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "x" Then
        intCountSurroundingCells = intCountSurroundingCells + 1
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = "x" Then
        intCountSurroundingCells = intCountSurroundingCells + 1
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "x" Then
        intCountSurroundingCells = intCountSurroundingCells + 1
    End If

    If myCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = "x" Then
        intCountSurroundingCells = intCountSurroundingCells + 1
    End If

    If intCountSurroundingCells = 0 Then
    Else
        myCell.Value = intCountSurroundingCells
    End If

End If

Next

End Sub
```

declared strBoardSize:

```
Sub SetBoardSize()

strBoardSize = "Board9x9"

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value in `strBoardSize` ?

Comment: Edited, may you look if anything is wrong?

Comment: Do you have named ranges like "Board9x9" etc ?  If not then you need to either create them, or change how you're passing the range to the `WorkOutMines` sub.

Comment: I have 3 tables named 'Board9x9', 'Board16x16' and 'Board16x30'. Not sure what's wrong with all this.

Comment: Where is `strBoardSize` declared, and how are you calling `WorkOutMines` ?

Comment: updated main message

Comment: It looks like in the procedure "CommandButton21_Click" you call the procedures SetBoardSize, ClearBoard, GenerateMines, and WorkOutMines. You're not showing us the code where you actually assign the value for strBoardSize, I am assuming this is in the SetBoardSize procedure? Without actually seeing what it is assigned we can only guess at your problem.

Comment: As of now, I'm little confused what you guys asking for. Just tell me where I could find it in my code and I would copy. Should it be ''Sub SetBoardSize()''?

Comment: Yes - show the code for `SetBoardSize()`

Comment: I'm updated it, but it's basically one line and probably there's a problem

Comment: Before this line `For Each myCell In Range(strBoardSize)` add a new line `Debug.Print "strBoardSize = " & strBoardSize`  - what is output when you run your code (it will show up in the immediate pane of the VB editor)?

Comment: same exact problem, ''Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' failed"

Comment: seems like I've done it myself, have another problems tho, but probably won't ask for a help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare that variable in the "WorkoutMines" sub.

```
Dim strBoardSize as String
```

Then you can set the variable the variable

```
strBoardSize = "Board9x9"
```

If you don't declare the variable in the same sub procedure, it won't keep it's value.

Comment: I added another answer because I was having trouble getting my code to show up as code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to create the variable "strBoardSize" and set the range that you want that to be. If "strBoardSize" is a named range in a workbook the correct syntax would be:

```
For Each myCell in Range("strBoardSize")
```

Comment: Edited my main message, is there any problem with strBoardSize?

Comment: You still don't declare the variable "strBoardSize" anywhere in the code that I can see. How is "strBoardSize" set? I don't see anywhere in your code where "strBoardSize" is set to either "Board 9X9" or "Board 16X16".

Comment: Is this all of your code? In order to declare "strBoardSize" in on sub and use it in another, you would have to declare it outside individual subs. Also, using: For Each myCell In Range(strBoardSize), makes it look like you have a range named "Board9X9", is that true?

Comment: not whole code, but it's all for declaring strBoardSize. Yes, I have a range called Board9x9, as well as Board16x16 and Board16x30